# Help with block diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a diagram as follows:

[image]

but I'm stucked drawing it, specially the blocks D, E and F. Anyone can help me?

This is the code that I've written:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, shapes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}},
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
node distance = 2mm and -2mm,   % Global setup of box spacing
start chain = going above,    % General flow is top-to-bottom
%
LA/.style = {Stealth-},
base1/.style = {draw,
    minimum size=6ex, inner sep=2mm, align=center,
    on chain, join=by LA},
base2/.style = {draw,
    minimum size=8ex, inner sep=2mm, align=center,
    on chain, join=by LA},
sbox/.style = {base1, rectangle, text width=11em},
sbox2/.style = {base2, rectangle, text width=8em},
sbox3/.style = {base2, rectangle, text width=8em},
wbox/.style = {base1, rectangle, text width=25em},
term/.style = {sbox, rectangle, rounded corners},
test/.style = {base1, diamond, aspect=1.5,
    inner xsep=0mm, text width=8em},
]
% from bottom to top
\node (n1)  [term]          {END};
\node (n2)  [wbox]          {I};
\node (n4)  [sbox3]                        {DDDDDDDD};
% left column
\node (n5a) [sbox, suppress join, above  left=of n4]    {TTTTTT};
\node (n7a) [sbox]          {BBBBBBBB};
% right column
\node (n5b) [sbox, suppress join, above right=of n4]    {TTTTT};
\node (n7b) [sbox]          {CCCCCCCC};
% top column2
\node (n8)  [wbox, suppress join, above=of n7a.north -| n4]   {AAAAAAAA};
\node (n11) [term]          {\large START};
%
%\draw[LA]   (n4) edge (n3)
%(n8) edge (n4);
%\draw[LA]   (n7a) edge (n7a |- n8.south)  (n3) -| (n5a);
%\draw[LA]   (n7b) edge (n7b |- n8.south)  (n3) -| (n5b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some things I did not understand the purpose. Anyway, I left your styles in and created something that looks like your screen shot from them. (But really, one should not always try to use `chains` at any cost.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows.meta, chains}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    node distance = 1.5em and 2em,   % Global setup of box spacing
    start chain = going above,    % General flow is top-to-bottom
    %
    LA/.style = {Stealth-},
    base1/.style = {draw,
        minimum size=6ex, inner sep=2mm, align=center,
        join=by LA},
    base2/.style = {draw,
        minimum size=8ex, inner sep=2mm, align=center,
         join=by LA},
    sbox/.style = {base1, rectangle, text width=11em},
    sbox2/.style = {base2, rectangle, text width=8em},
    sbox3/.style = {base2, rectangle, text width=8em},
    wbox/.style = {base1, rectangle, text width=25em},
    term/.style = {sbox, rectangle, rounded corners},
    test/.style = {base1, diamond, aspect=1.5,
        inner xsep=0mm, text width=8em},
    font=\sffamily
    ]
  % from bottom to top
  \node (n1)  [on chain,term]          {END};
  \node (n2)  [on chain,sbox3]          {I};
  \node (n3)  [on chain,sbox3]          {H};
  \node (n4)  [on chain,sbox3]          {G};
  \node[above=of n4,anchor=south east,xshift=-0.75em] (n5a) [sbox3] {B};
  \node[above=of n4,anchor=south west,xshift=0.75em] (n5b) [sbox3] {C};
  \node[left=of n5a,sbox3] (n6b) {E};
  \node[above=of n6b,sbox3] (n6a) {D};
  \node[below=of n6b,sbox3] (n6c) {F};
  \node[right=of n5b,sbox3] (n7b) {E};
  \node[above=of n7b,sbox3] (n7a) {D};
  \node[below=of n7b,sbox3] (n7c) {F};
  \path (n5a.north) -- (n5b.north) node[midway,above=1.5em,sbox3] (n8) {A};
  \node[above=of n8,term] (n9) {START};
  \foreach \Z in {a,b,c}
   {\draw[LA] (n6\Z.east) -- ++ (1em,0) |- (n5a);
   \draw[LA] (n7\Z.west) -- ++ (-1em,0) |- (n5b);}
  \draw[LA] (n4.150) -- (n4.150|-n5a.south);
  \draw[LA] (n4.30) -- (n4.30|-n5b.south);
  \draw[-Stealth] (n8.-150) -- (n8.-150|-n5a.north);
  \draw[-Stealth] (n8.-30) -- (n8.-30|-n5b.north);
  \draw[LA] (n8) -- (n9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the code, and also for the advice

Answer (score 0):

your MWE is somehow familiar to me ;-)

I would rewrote it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}},}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
node distance = 6mm and 5mm,  % Global setup of box spacing
  start chain = going above,    % General flow is bottom-to-top
%
  LA/.style = {Stealth-},
 LAA/.style = {Stealth-Stealth},
base/.style = {draw, inner sep=3mm, align=center,
               on chain},
 box/.style = {base, text width=#1,
               join=by LA},
 box/.default = 11em,
sbox/.style = {base, text width=7em},
term/.style = {box=5em, rounded corners, font=\large,
               on chain, join=by LA},
test/.style = {base, diamond, aspect=1.5,
               inner xsep=0mm, text width=8em,
               on chain, join=by LA},
                ]
% from bottom to top
\node (n1)  [box=5em]   {END};
\node (n2)  [box]       {I};
\node (n3)  [box]       {G};
\node (n4)  [box]       {H};
% left sub column
\node (n5a) [sbox,
             above  left=of n4.north]   {B};
% right sub column
\node (n5b) [sbox,
             above right=of n4.north]   {C};
% top column
\node (n6)  [box, suppress join,
             above=of n5a.north -| n4]  {A};
\node (n11) [term]  {START};
% left column
\node (nL1) [sbox,
             left=of n5a.west |- n4]    {F};
\node (nL2) [sbox]    {E};
\node (nL3) [sbox]    {D};
% right column
\node (nR1) [sbox,
             right=of n5b.east |- n4]    {F};
\node (nR2) [sbox]    {E};
\node (nR3) [sbox]    {D};
% connection notincluded in join macro
\draw[LA]   (n4.north -| n5a) edge (n5a)
            (n4.north -| n5b) edge (n5b)
            (n5a) edge (n5a |- n6.south)
            (n5b) edge (n5b |- n6.south)
% left column
            (nL2) edge (n5a)
            (nR2)  -- (n5b)
            ;
\coordinate[left =2mm of n5a.west] (L);
\coordinate[right=2mm of n5b.east] (R);
\draw[LAA]   (nL1)-| (L) |- (nL3);
\draw[LAA]   (nR1)-| (R) |- (nR3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]